# Comparing 2 columns from different files print matching columns

Tags: bash, awk

I know similar questions have been asked which has led me write the current code but I am still not able to get the correct output. 
Question:
If Column 1 (in file 1) matches Column 5 (in file 2), print all columns in file 2 and columns 3 and 4 (in file 1) to a new file.

File 1 (tab-delimited)

```
NJE_00001   rmf 6.2 Ribosome modulation factor
NJE_00002   rlm 7.1 Ribosomal RNA large subunit methyltransferase
NJE_00003   gnt 6.2 putative D-xylose utilization operon
NJE_00004   prp 4.1 2-methylisocitrate lyase
```

File 2 (tab-delimited)

```
AFC_04390   rmf 5.6 protein1    NJE_00001
AFC_04391   rlm 2.5 protein54   NJE_00002
AFC_04392   gnt 2.1 protein8    NJE_00003
AFC_04393   prp 4.1 protein5    NJE_00004
```

Desired Output (tab-delimited)

```
AFC_04390   rmf 5.6 protein1    NJE_00001   6.2 Ribosome modulation factor
AFC_04391   rlm 2.5 protein54   NJE_00002   7.1 Ribosomal RNA large subunit methyltransferase
AFC_04392   gnt 2.1 protein8    NJE_00003   6.2 putative D-xylose utilization operon
AFC_04393   prp 4.1 protein5    NJE_00004   5.9 2-methylisocitrate lyase
```

What I've tried:

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$3"\t"$4; next} ($5 in a) {print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5 "\t" a[$1]}' file1.tsv file2.tsv > file.out

awk -F '\t' 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} {if ($5 in a) {print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5 "\t" a[$1]}}' file1.tsv file2.tsv > file.out

awk -F '\t' 'NR==FNR {h[$1]=$3"\t"$4; next} ($5 in h) {print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5 "\t" h[$1]}' file1.tsv file2.tsv > file.out
```

They've all given the same outputs which is identical to file 2. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '
     BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
     NR==FNR { a[$1]=$3 OFS $4; next }
     { print $0, a[$5] }
' file1 file2
AFC_04390       rmf     5.6     protein1        NJE_00001       6.2     Ribosome modulation factor
AFC_04391       rlm     2.5     protein54       NJE_00002       7.1     Ribosomal RNA large subunit methyltransferase
AFC_04392       gnt     2.1     protein8        NJE_00003       6.2     putative D-xylose utilization operon
AFC_04393       prp     4.1     protein5        NJE_00004       4.1     2-methylisocitrate lyase
```

Comment: Since the files are already tab-delimited, when would you use -F '\t' and BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } or what is the difference between these two?

Comment: `-F'\t'` sets FS to \t. `BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }` sets both FS and OFS to \t. Definitely use `BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }` over any other construct if you want both FS and OFS to be set to the same hard-coded value. If you're not using OFS then `-F'\t'` is just a bit briefer than `BEGIN{FS="\t"}` or `-v FS='\t'` or `awk 'script' FS='\t' file` but functionally they're all equivalent. If you need to change FS between files then `awk 'script' FS=x file1 FS=y file2` and if you want OFS to be set to a varying FS then `awk 'FNR==1{OFS=FS; $0=$0} script' FS=x file1 FS=y file2`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  val=$1
  $1=$2=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  a[val]=$0
  next
}
($NF in a){
  print $0,a[$NF]
}
'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                 ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{              ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Input_file1 is being read.
  val=$1              ##Creating variable val which has $1 of current line.
  $1=$2=""            ##Nullifying first and second fields here.
  sub(/^ +/,"")       ##Substituting initial space with NULL in current line.
  a[val]=$0           ##Creating an array named a with index val and value of current line.
  next                ##next will skip further lines from here.
}
($NF in a){           ##Checking condition if $NF(last field of current line) is present in array a then do following.
  print $0,a[$NF]     ##Printing current line with array a with index $NF value.
}
' file1 file2         ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your files are sorted on the first and fifth columns respectively like in your sample, it's easy to do with [`join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html)

```
join -t$'\t' -11 -25 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,1.3,1.4 file1.tsv file2.tsv > joined.tsv
```

If not sorted, use `<(sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 file1.tsv)` and/or `<(sort -t$'\t' -k5,5 file2.tsv)` instead of just the filename as arguments to `join`.